# Get Swiftmailer's settings from a Controller in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have this config in my config.yml file

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

How do I read these settings from a controller in order to check whether spool has been set or not?

Answer (score 1):

You could move spool config in `parameters.yml`, for example:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    mailer_spool: { type: memory }
```

And then replace this line in `config.yml` with parameter:

```
# app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    spool: "%mailer_spool%"
```

Now in *any* controller you could get this spool config like:

```
public function yourAction()
{
    $spool = $this->getParameter('mailer_spool');
}
```